# Using MyGeneration, doodads, and Oracle XE, is it possible to implement an "auto number primary key" scheme?

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql, mygeneration

Using MyGeneration, doodads, and Oracle XE, is it possible to implement an "auto number primary key" scheme?

Problem facts:
I am using Oracle XE. I have implemented the following table and trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE  "USERS" 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(100), 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_USERS" 
  before insert on "USERS"               
  for each row  
begin   
    select "USERS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW.ID from dual; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_USERS" ENABLE
/
```

MyGeneration / Doodads created the following stored proc...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "XXX"."PI_USERS"
(
    p_ID IN USERS.ID%type,
    p_USER_NAME IN USERS.USER_NAME%type,
    p_PASSWORD IN USERS.PASSWORD%type,
    p_EMAIL IN USERS.EMAIL%type
)
IS
BEGIN


    INSERT
    INTO USERS
    (
        ID,
        USER_NAME,
        PASSWORD,
        EMAIL
    )
    VALUES
    (
        p_ID,
        p_USER_NAME,
        p_PASSWORD,
        p_EMAIL
    );
END PI_USERS;
```

The sequence and trigger combination is working fine.   The BusinessEntity class in C# does not receive the new ID.

Any recommended ways to allow the calling code receive the new record ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Doodads, so not sure if this is what it is expecting, but if you change the procedure like below using the `returning` clause and make the p_ID parameter `in out` the p_ID parameter should hold the newly added ID after it is executed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "XXX"."PI_USERS"
(
    p_ID IN OUT USERS.ID%type,
    p_USER_NAME IN USERS.USER_NAME%type,
    p_PASSWORD IN USERS.PASSWORD%type,
    p_EMAIL IN USERS.EMAIL%type
)
IS
BEGIN


    INSERT
    INTO USERS
    (
        ID,
        USER_NAME,
        PASSWORD,
        EMAIL
    )
    VALUES
    (
        p_ID,
        p_USER_NAME,
        p_PASSWORD,
        p_EMAIL
    )
    RETURNING ID INTO p_ID;

END PI_USERS;
```

Comment: VERY VERY COOL... We used your recommended change to the stored procs... It worked!

On the C# side, we will be adjusting the generator to create the following change...

  private IDbCommand CreateParameters(OracleCommand cmd)
  {
   OracleParameter p;
  
   p = cmd.Parameters.Add(Parameters.ID);
   p.SourceColumn = ColumnNames.ID;
   p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
            p.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a sequence? If your preference is to use TAPI I still think the ID and WHO columns are best served in a trigger on a sequence. Is the issue the need for a pure, dense sequence where there are no skipped numbers?